# PySpark left outer join giving values as None

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Following is structure of `dfEvents` spark dataframe.

```
root
 |-- artist: string (nullable = true)
 |-- auth: string (nullable = true)
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- itemInSession: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- length: double (nullable = true)
 |-- level: string (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- method: string (nullable = true)
 |-- page: string (nullable = true)
 |-- registration: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sessionId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- song: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: long (nullable = true)
 |-- userAgent: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
```

and following is the structure of `dfSongs` spark dataframe

```
root
 |-- artist_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- artist_latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- artist_location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- artist_longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- artist_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration: double (nullable = true)
 |-- num_songs: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- song_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
```

JOIN Query

```
condition = (( dfEvents["artist"] == dfSongs["artist_name"]) & (dfEvents["song"] == dfSongs["title"]) )
plays = dfEvents.join(dfSongs, condition, "left_outer").select(dfEvents["ts"], dfEvents["userId"], dfEvents["level"], dfSongs["song_id"], dfSongs["artist_id"], dfEvents["sessionId"], dfEvents["location"], dfEvents["userAgent"])
plays.limit(5).toPandas()
```

[image]

`song_id` and `artist_id` are coming as `None` in all rows. I tried alias function but still not working.

EDIT 1 : Sample Data
dfEvents has around ~8000 rows so adding only few here

```
[Row(artist='Harmonia', auth='Logged In', firstName='Ryan', gender='M', itemInSession=0, lastName='Smith', length=655.77751, level='free', location='San Jose-Sunnyvale-Santa Clara, CA', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1541016707796.0, sessionId=583, song='Sehr kosmisch', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 06:00:26.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"', userId=26),
 Row(artist='The Prodigy', auth='Logged In', firstName='Ryan', gender='M', itemInSession=1, lastName='Smith', length=260.07465, level='free', location='San Jose-Sunnyvale-Santa Clara, CA', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1541016707796.0, sessionId=583, song='The Big Gundown', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 06:11:21.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"', userId=26),
 Row(artist='Train', auth='Logged In', firstName='Ryan', gender='M', itemInSession=2, lastName='Smith', length=205.45261, level='free', location='San Jose-Sunnyvale-Santa Clara, CA', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1541016707796.0, sessionId=583, song='Marry Me', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 06:15:41.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"', userId=26),
 Row(artist='Sony Wonder', auth='Logged In', firstName='Samuel', gender='M', itemInSession=0, lastName='Gonzalez', length=218.06975, level='free', location='Houston-The Woodlands-Sugar Land, TX', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540492941796.0, sessionId=597, song='Blackbird', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 09:14:09.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.77.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.5 Safari/537.77.4"', userId=61),
 Row(artist='Van Halen', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=2, lastName='Levine', length=289.38404, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='Best Of Both Worlds (Remastered Album Version)', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:18:55.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80),
 Row(artist='Magic Sam', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=3, lastName='Levine', length=132.04853, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='Call Me If You Need Me', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:23:44.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80),
 Row(artist='Edward Sharpe & The Magnetic Zeros', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=4, lastName='Levine', length=306.31138, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='Home', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:25:56.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80),
 Row(artist='Usher featuring will.i.am', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=5, lastName='Levine', length=395.72853, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='OMG', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:31:02.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80),
 Row(artist='Helen Reddy', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=7, lastName='Levine', length=176.50893, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='Candle On The Water', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:37:37.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80),
 Row(artist='Taylor Swift', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=8, lastName='Levine', length=201.06404, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='Our Song', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:40:33.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80),
 Row(artist='Sean Paul', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=9, lastName='Levine', length=245.34159, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='Baby Boy [feat. Beyonce]', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:43:54.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80),
 Row(artist='Soundgarden', auth='Logged In', firstName='Lily', gender='F', itemInSession=0, lastName='Koch', length=272.19546, level='paid', location='Chicago-Naperville-Elgin, IL-IN-WI', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1541048010796.0, sessionId=582, song='Black Hole Sun', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:44:16.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"', userId=15),
 Row(artist='The Killers', auth='Logged In', firstName='Tegan', gender='F', itemInSession=10, lastName='Levine', length=360.75057, level='paid', location='Portland-South Portland, ME', method='PUT', page='NextSong', registration=1540794356796.0, sessionId=602, song='Human', status='200', ts='2018-11-15 11:47:59.796000', userAgent='"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"', userId=80)]
```

dfSongs has only 71 rows and adding all here

```
[Row(artist_id='ARDR4AC1187FB371A1', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Montserrat Caballé;Placido Domingo;Vicente Sardinero;Judith Blegen;Sherrill Milnes;Georg Solti', duration=511.16363, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBAYLL12A8C138AF9', title='Sono andati? Fingevo di dormire', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AREBBGV1187FB523D2', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Houston, TX', artist_longitude=None, artist_name="Mike Jones (Featuring CJ_ Mello & Lil' Bran)", duration=173.66159, num_songs=1, song_id='SOOLYAZ12A6701F4A6', title='Laws Patrolling (Album Version)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARMAC4T1187FB3FA4C', artist_latitude=40.82624, artist_location='Morris Plains, NJ', artist_longitude=-74.47995, artist_name='The Dillinger Escape Plan', duration=207.77751, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBBUGU12A8C13E95D', title='Setting Fire to Sleeping Giants', year=2004),
 Row(artist_id='ARPBNLO1187FB3D52F', artist_latitude=40.71455, artist_location='New York, NY', artist_longitude=-74.00712, artist_name='Tiny Tim', duration=43.36281, num_songs=1, song_id='SOAOIBZ12AB01815BE', title='I Hold Your Hand In Mine [Live At Royal Albert Hall]', year=2000),
 Row(artist_id='ARDNS031187B9924F0', artist_latitude=32.67828, artist_location='Georgia', artist_longitude=-83.22295, artist_name='Tim Wilson', duration=186.48771, num_songs=1, song_id='SONYPOM12A8C13B2D7', title='I Think My Wife Is Running Around On Me (Taco Hell)', year=2005),
 Row(artist_id='ARNF6401187FB57032', artist_latitude=40.79086, artist_location='New York, NY [Manhattan]', artist_longitude=-73.96644, artist_name='Sophie B. Hawkins', duration=305.162, num_songs=1, song_id='SONWXQJ12A8C134D94', title='The Ballad Of Sleeping Beauty', year=1994),
 Row(artist_id='ARLTWXK1187FB5A3F8', artist_latitude=32.74863, artist_location='Fort Worth, TX', artist_longitude=-97.32925, artist_name='King Curtis', duration=326.00771, num_songs=1, song_id='SODREIN12A58A7F2E5', title='A Whiter Shade Of Pale (Live @ Fillmore West)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARPFHN61187FB575F6', artist_latitude=41.88415, artist_location='Chicago, IL', artist_longitude=-87.63241, artist_name='Lupe Fiasco', duration=279.97995, num_songs=1, song_id='SOWQTQZ12A58A7B63E', title='Streets On Fire (Explicit Album Version)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARI2JSK1187FB496EF', artist_latitude=51.50632, artist_location='London, England', artist_longitude=-0.12714, artist_name='Nick Ingman;Gavyn Wright', duration=111.62077, num_songs=1, song_id='SODUJBS12A8C132150', title='Wessex Loses a Bride', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR0RCMP1187FB3F427', artist_latitude=30.08615, artist_location='Beaumont, TX', artist_longitude=-94.10158, artist_name='Billie Jo Spears', duration=133.32853, num_songs=1, song_id='SOGXHEG12AB018653E', title='It Makes No Difference Now', year=1992),
 Row(artist_id='AROUOZZ1187B9ABE51', artist_latitude=40.79195, artist_location='New York, NY [Spanish Harlem]', artist_longitude=-73.94512, artist_name='Willie Bobo', duration=168.25424, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBZBAZ12A6D4F8742', title='Spanish Grease', year=1997),
 Row(artist_id='AR9AWNF1187B9AB0B4', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Seattle, Washington USA', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Kenny G featuring Daryl Hall', duration=236.93016, num_songs=1, song_id='SOZHPGD12A8C1394FE', title='Baby Come To Me', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR47JEX1187B995D81', artist_latitude=37.83721, artist_location='Nevada, MO', artist_longitude=-94.35868, artist_name='SUE THOMPSON', duration=124.86485, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBLGCN12AB0183212', title='James (Hold The Ladder Steady)', year=1985),
 Row(artist_id='ARKFYS91187B98E58F', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Jeff And Sheri Easter', duration=267.7024, num_songs=1, song_id='SOYMRWW12A6D4FAB14', title='The Moon And I (Ordinary Day Album Version)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR10USD1187B99F3F1', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Burlington, Ontario, Canada', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Tweeterfriendly Music', duration=189.57016, num_songs=1, song_id='SOHKNRJ12A6701D1F8', title='Drop of Rain', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARB29H41187B98F0EF', artist_latitude=41.88415, artist_location='Chicago', artist_longitude=-87.63241, artist_name='Terry Callier', duration=342.56934, num_songs=1, song_id='SOGNCJP12A58A80271', title='Do You Finally Need A Friend', year=1972),
 Row(artist_id='ARQGYP71187FB44566', artist_latitude=34.31109, artist_location='Mineola, AR', artist_longitude=-94.02978, artist_name='Jimmy Wakely', duration=151.84934, num_songs=1, song_id='SOWTBJW12AC468AC6E', title='Broken-Down Merry-Go-Round', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARMBR4Y1187B9990EB', artist_latitude=37.77916, artist_location='California - SF', artist_longitude=-122.42005, artist_name='David Martin', duration=241.47546, num_songs=1, song_id='SOTTDKS12AB018D69B', title='It Wont Be Christmas', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR36F9J1187FB406F1', artist_latitude=56.27609, artist_location='Denmark', artist_longitude=9.51695, artist_name='Bombay Rockers', duration=230.71302, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBKWDJ12A8C13B2F3', title='Wild Rose (Back 2 Basics Mix)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARBEBBY1187B9B43DB', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Gainesville, FL', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Tom Petty', duration=236.17261, num_songs=1, song_id='SOFFKZS12AB017F194', title='A Higher Place (Album Version)', year=1994),
 Row(artist_id='ARIK43K1187B9AE54C', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Beverly Hills, CA', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Lionel Richie', duration=307.3824, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBONFF12A6D4F84D8', title='Tonight Will Be Alright', year=1986),
 Row(artist_id='ARD842G1187B997376', artist_latitude=43.64856, artist_location='Toronto, Ontario, Canada', artist_longitude=-79.38533, artist_name='Blue Rodeo', duration=491.12771, num_songs=1, song_id='SOHUOAP12A8AE488E9', title='Floating', year=1987),
 Row(artist_id='ARQ9BO41187FB5CF1F', artist_latitude=40.99471, artist_location='Pennsylvania', artist_longitude=-77.60454, artist_name='John Davis', duration=183.17016, num_songs=1, song_id='SOMVWWT12A58A7AE05', title='Knocked Out Of The Park', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR3JMC51187B9AE49D', artist_latitude=28.53823, artist_location='Orlando, FL', artist_longitude=-81.37739, artist_name='Backstreet Boys', duration=236.25098, num_songs=1, song_id='SOPVXLX12A8C1402D5', title='Larger Than Life', year=1999),
 Row(artist_id='ARGCY1Y1187B9A4FA5', artist_latitude=36.16778, artist_location='Nashville, TN.', artist_longitude=-86.77836, artist_name='Gloriana', duration=153.33832, num_songs=1, song_id='SOQOTLQ12AB01868D0', title='Clementina Santafè', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARH4Z031187B9A71F2', artist_latitude=40.73197, artist_location='Newark, NJ', artist_longitude=-74.17418, artist_name='Faye Adams', duration=156.39465, num_songs=1, song_id='SOVYKGO12AB0187199', title='Crazy Mixed Up World', year=1961),
 Row(artist_id='ARBGXIG122988F409D', artist_latitude=37.77916, artist_location='California - SF', artist_longitude=-122.42005, artist_name='Steel Rain', duration=173.19138, num_songs=1, song_id='SOOJPRH12A8C141995', title='Loaded Like A Gun', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARNNKDK1187B98BBD5', artist_latitude=45.80726, artist_location='Zagreb Croatia', artist_longitude=15.9676, artist_name='Jinx', duration=407.37914, num_songs=1, song_id='SOFNOQK12AB01840FC', title='Kutt Free (DJ Volume Remix)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARAJPHH1187FB5566A', artist_latitude=40.7038, artist_location='Queens, NY', artist_longitude=-73.83168, artist_name='The Shangri-Las', duration=164.80608, num_songs=1, song_id='SOYTPEP12AB0180E7B', title='Twist and Shout', year=1964),
 Row(artist_id='ARGSJW91187B9B1D6B', artist_latitude=35.21962, artist_location='North Carolina', artist_longitude=-80.01955, artist_name='JennyAnyKind', duration=218.77506, num_songs=1, song_id='SOQHXMF12AB0182363', title='Young Boy Blues', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARAGB2O1187FB3A161', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Pucho & His Latin Soul Brothers', duration=338.23302, num_songs=1, song_id='SOLEYHO12AB0188A85', title='Got My Mojo Workin', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARC43071187B990240', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Wisner, LA', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Wayne Watson', duration=245.21098, num_songs=1, song_id='SOKEJEJ12A8C13E0D0', title='The Urgency (LP Version)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARIG6O41187B988BDD', artist_latitude=37.16793, artist_location='United States', artist_longitude=-95.84502, artist_name='Richard Souther', duration=228.5971, num_songs=1, song_id='SOUQQEA12A8C134B1B', title='High Tide', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARMJAGH1187FB546F3', artist_latitude=35.14968, artist_location='Memphis, TN', artist_longitude=-90.04892, artist_name='The Box Tops', duration=148.03546, num_songs=1, song_id='SOCIWDW12A8C13D406', title='Soul Deep', year=1969),
 Row(artist_id='ARGUVEV1187B98BA17', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Sierra Maestra', duration=313.12934, num_songs=1, song_id='SOGOSOV12AF72A285E', title='¿Dónde va Chichi?', year=1997),
 Row(artist_id='AR1Y2PT1187FB5B9CE', artist_latitude=27.94017, artist_location='Brandon', artist_longitude=-82.32547, artist_name='John Wesley', duration=484.62322, num_songs=1, song_id='SOLLHMX12AB01846DC', title='The Emperor Falls', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARP6N5A1187B99D1A3', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Hamtramck, MI', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Mitch Ryder', duration=207.43791, num_songs=1, song_id='SOXILUQ12A58A7C72A', title='Jenny Take a Ride', year=2004),
 Row(artist_id='AREDL271187FB40F44', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Soul Mekanik', duration=45.66159, num_songs=1, song_id='SOPEGZN12AB0181B3D', title='Get Your Head Stuck On Your Neck', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AREDBBQ1187B98AFF5', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Eddie Calvert', duration=138.63138, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBBXLX12A58A79DDA', title='Erica (2005 Digital Remaster)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR7G5I41187FB4CE6C', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='London, England', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Adam Ant', duration=233.40363, num_songs=1, song_id='SONHOTT12A8C13493C', title='Something Girls', year=1982),
 Row(artist_id='ARGSAFR1269FB35070', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Blingtones', duration=29.54404, num_songs=1, song_id='SOTCKKY12AB018A141', title='Sonnerie lalaleulé hi houuu', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARI3BMM1187FB4255E', artist_latitude=38.8991, artist_location='Washington', artist_longitude=-77.029, artist_name='Alice Stuart', duration=220.78649, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBEBDG12A58A76D60', title='Kassie Jones', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR0IAWL1187B9A96D0', artist_latitude=8.4177, artist_location='Panama', artist_longitude=-80.11278, artist_name='Danilo Perez', duration=197.19791, num_songs=1, song_id='SONSKXP12A8C13A2C9', title='Native Soul', year=2003),
 Row(artist_id='ARD7TVE1187B99BFB1', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='California - LA', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Casual', duration=218.93179, num_songs=1, song_id='SOMZWCG12A8C13C480', title="I Didn't Mean To", year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARWB3G61187FB49404', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Hamilton, Ohio', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Steve Morse', duration=363.85914, num_songs=1, song_id='SODAUVL12A8C13D184', title='Prognosis', year=2000),
 Row(artist_id='AREVWGE1187B9B890A', artist_latitude=-13.442, artist_location='Noci (BA)', artist_longitude=-41.9952, artist_name='Bitter End', duration=282.43546, num_songs=1, song_id='SOFCHDR12AB01866EF', title='Living Hell', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARNTLGG11E2835DDB9', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Clp', duration=266.39628, num_songs=1, song_id='SOUDSGM12AC9618304', title='Insatiable (Instrumental Version)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR5KOSW1187FB35FF4', artist_latitude=49.80388, artist_location='Dubai UAE', artist_longitude=15.47491, artist_name='Elena', duration=269.58322, num_songs=1, song_id='SOZCTXZ12AB0182364', title='Setanta matins', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARGIWFO1187B9B55B7', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Five Bolt Main', duration=225.09669, num_songs=1, song_id='SOPSWQW12A6D4F8781', title='Made Like This (Live)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR1ZHYZ1187FB3C717', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Faiz Ali Faiz', duration=599.24853, num_songs=1, song_id='SOILPQQ12AB017E82A', title='Sohna Nee Sohna Data', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARD0S291187B9B7BF5', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='Ohio', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Rated R', duration=114.78159, num_songs=1, song_id='SOMJBYD12A6D4F8557', title='Keepin It Real (Skit)', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARKRRTF1187B9984DA', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Sonora Santanera', duration=177.47546, num_songs=1, song_id='SOXVLOJ12AB0189215', title='Amor De Cabaret', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARKULSX1187FB45F84', artist_latitude=39.49974, artist_location='Utah', artist_longitude=-111.54732, artist_name='Trafik', duration=424.12363, num_songs=1, song_id='SOQVMXR12A81C21483', title='Salt In NYC', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARULZCI1241B9C8611', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Luna Orbit Project', duration=335.51628, num_songs=1, song_id='SOSWKAV12AB018FC91', title='Midnight Star', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARJIE2Y1187B994AB7', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Line Renaud', duration=152.92036, num_songs=1, song_id='SOUPIRU12A6D4FA1E1', title='Der Kleine Dompfaff', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR8ZCNI1187B9A069B', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Planet P Project', duration=269.81832, num_songs=1, song_id='SOIAZJW12AB01853F1', title='Pink World', year=1984),
 Row(artist_id='ARVBRGZ1187FB4675A', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Gwen Stefani', duration=290.55955, num_songs=1, song_id='SORRZGD12A6310DBC3', title='Harajuku Girls', year=2004),
 Row(artist_id='AR7SMBG1187B9B9066', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Los Manolos', duration=218.38322, num_songs=1, song_id='SOBCOSW12A8C13D398', title='Rumba De Barcelona', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARD7TVE1187B99BFB1', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='California - LA', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Casual', duration=259.44771, num_songs=1, song_id='SOQLGFP12A58A7800E', title='OAKtown', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR8IEZO1187B99055E', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Marc Shaiman', duration=149.86404, num_songs=1, song_id='SOINLJW12A8C13314C', title='City Slickers', year=2008),
 Row(artist_id='AROGWRA122988FEE45', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Christos Dantis', duration=243.82649, num_songs=1, song_id='SOSLAVG12A8C13397F', title='Den Pai Alo', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR051KA1187B98B2FF', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Wilks', duration=261.51138, num_songs=1, song_id='SOLYIBD12A8C135045', title='Music is what we love', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR62SOJ1187FB47BB5', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Chase & Status', duration=337.68444, num_songs=1, song_id='SOGVQGJ12AB017F169', title='Ten Tonne', year=2005),
 Row(artist_id='ARYKCQI1187FB3B18F', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Tesla', duration=290.29832, num_songs=1, song_id='SOXLBJT12A8C140925', title='Caught In A Dream', year=2004),
 Row(artist_id='ARNPAGP1241B9C7FD4', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='lextrical', duration=165.69424, num_songs=1, song_id='SOZVMJI12AB01808AF', title='Synthetic Dream', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARHHO3O1187B989413', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Bob Azzam', duration=191.84281, num_songs=1, song_id='SORAMLE12AB017C8B0', title='Auguri Cha Cha', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR7ZKHQ1187B98DD73', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Glad', duration=270.602, num_songs=1, song_id='SOTUKVB12AB0181477', title='Blessed Assurance', year=1993),
 Row(artist_id='ARXR32B1187FB57099', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Gob', duration=209.60608, num_songs=1, song_id='SOFSOCN12A8C143F5D', title='Face the Ashes', year=2007),
 Row(artist_id='ARNTLGG11E2835DDB9', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Clp', duration=338.31138, num_songs=1, song_id='SOZQDIU12A58A7BCF6', title='Superconfidential', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='ARL7K851187B99ACD2', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='Andy Andy', duration=226.35057, num_songs=1, song_id='SOMUYGI12AB0188633', title='La Culpa', year=0),
 Row(artist_id='AR558FS1187FB45658', artist_latitude=None, artist_location='', artist_longitude=None, artist_name='40 Grit', duration=75.67628, num_songs=1, song_id='SOGDBUF12A8C140FAA', title='Intro', year=2003)]
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: I expect it means that no matching `dfSongs` records were found.  You haven't shown us any sample data, so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Yes as per current output but in reality there are matching rows.

Comment: can you share both dataframe as sample?then its easy to find out problem.

Comment: Are you sure `&` is the right operator to use in the condition, instead of `and`?  Ampersand is typically used as a bitwise operator, not a logical operator.

Comment: When using `and` error shows up like `ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
`

Comment: Ok then, some packages do require `&`, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Without seeing some sample data, I don't think we can really help any further.

Comment: Added some sample data.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is the `length` and `duration` fields.  Those are double datatype, and unless they were populated very carefully, I can imagine they might not be _exactly_ equal...

Comment: Even removing the length/duration condition output is same for me.

Comment: As far as I can see, those two samples are both `dfSongs` records.  You have not posted any `dfEvents` records...

Comment: As far as I can see, _none_ of the `length` and `duration` values match up...

Comment: @JohnGordon even if i remove the length and duration condition, i am getting song_id and artist_id as None. I have update condition now.

Comment: Also, none of the `artist` values match any of the `artist_name` values.  Did you actually look over this data?

Comment: Can you give us an example of one `dfSongs` record and one `dfEvents` record that you expect to be a match?

Comment: have you tried inner join? the matching records might be so low that you might have missed them in the output. I suggest testing once with the inner join to check whether the result will be empty or contain the matching records. if it was empty then there is a logical error in the code that should be found. otherwise, the question is answered, and there is no error.

Comment: @AminHeydariAlashti Yes you're correct it turned out there is only one matching record and i found using inner join.

Comment: i would also change the strings to lowercase on the join conditions

Comment: @iambdot exactly I tried that and still matching rows were 1.

Comment: The reason is simple: you are using `left_outer` join and none of the `dfEvents["artist"] == dfSongs["artist_name"]` or `dfEvents["song"] == dfSongs["title"]` conditions have any match. Obviously you are getting all empty rows for dfSongs in join. You need look back at your data querying strategy.

Comment: @AzharKhan  I agree

Comment: Thanks @AzharKhan I do understand the results of left outer join and how it works. I was just curious initially why song_id and artist_id coming as None and eventually I found out there are very few matches in my dataset using inner join and i missed them in left outer join's result.

Comment: left outer join is not the best join to use. Ideally, you should use inner join but that would result into very few matches. You need some matching strategies - you can try 1. fuzzy matching
2. exploding the artist names in dfSongs as there are multiple artists in the same cell
3. remove terms like (skit), (live) etc
Calculate the match % and do a manual QC after each strategy, to see where else you can improve.